# MIPS Assembly Language Stack Pointer Merge Sort

Tags: assembly, mips, mergesort

I am working on a Merge sorting algorithm in MIPS Assembly Language and am having problems with my stack pointer and return address. It seems I'm popping off too early when working my way out of the merge sort algorithm. I just have a list of 20 random numbers that are supposed to sort. In theory, that is supposed to work, but at this point its not working because of my stack. I am having the problem coming out of the merge code. Any help would be greatly appreciative. I will send whole code if need be. I am running on xspim or spimsal. Have been working on this for many days now.

```
merge_sort:
            slt     $t0,    $s0,    $s1     # $t0=1 if lo<hi
            bne     $t0,    $zero,  L1      # if lo<hi branch to L1

            jr      $ra                                                          

       L1:     add     $t0,    $s0,    $s1     # t0 = lo+hi
            div     $s2,    $t0,    2       # m=lo+hi/2

            addi    $sp,    $sp,    -20     #increase stack
            sw      $ra,    16($sp)         #push values on stack
            sw      $a0,    12($sp) 
            sw      $s2,    8($sp)          # m
            sw      $s1,    4($sp)          # hi
            sw      $s0,    0($sp)          # lo

            add     $s1,    $s2,    $zero             # hi=m

            jal     merge_sort              # merge_sort(a(a0), ?, $s0,    $) also $ra

            addi    $sp,    $sp,    -20     #increase stack

            sw      $ra,    16($sp)         #push values on stack
            sw      $a0,    12($sp)   
            sw      $s2,    8($sp)          # m
            sw      $s1,    4($sp)          # hi
            sw      $s0,    0($sp)          # lo

            addi    $s0,    $s2,    1       # lo=m+1


            jal     merge_sort           # merge_sort also $ra(return address)

            addi    $sp,    $sp,    20   #decrement and pop values off stack
            lw      $s0,    0($sp)
            lw      $s1,    4($sp)
            lw      $s2,    8($sp)
            lw      $a0,    12($sp)


            jal     merge                  #jump to merge also return address
            lw      $s0,    0($sp)         #load values 
            lw      $s1,    4($sp)
            lw      $s2,    8($sp)
            lw      $a0,    12($sp)
            lw      $ra,    16($sp)
            addi    $sp,    $sp     20    #decrement stack

            jr      $ra                   #return to second merge_sort
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any MIPS assembler, but it seems clear to me that you are subtracting 20 from the stack pointer to provide some space for local storage, but you add 20 back on to the stack pointer in two places.

Comment: Cancel that last one, but that is correct. I create space so I can save new values during every recursion. After lo>hi, I add 20 back and load the values back into the registers and run a merge piece that is not on here. And then it adds 20 and loads the next set of values to go through merge_sort. Its recursive runs where I either get an infinite loop or something else.